# How can I print messages to console when using `future_lapply()`?

Tags: r, apply, r-future

I am running a function in parallel in R using `future_lapply()`, but I want to print a message to the R console.

I have something like this:

```
library(future.apply)

plan(multisession, workers = 2)
future_lapply(1:12, function(idx) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  print(paste0( idx, " completed."))
})
```

But the output of each `print()` is only displayed when all the processes end. How can I output them as soon as they are generated?

Comment: Try this: `future_lapply(1:12, function(idx) {
  Sys.sleep(idx^2); 
  message(paste0( idx, " completed."))
}, future.conditions = "message")`

Comment: @Roland It certainly works with your example, but not with `future_lapply(1:12, function(idx) {   Sys.sleep(5);    message(paste0( idx, " completed.")) }, future.conditions = "message")`. Messages are still output at the end of execution of `future_lapply()`

Comment: I might misunderstand something here. But with that code, all workers finish simultaneously and afterwards, the main process has to do practically nothing. In fact, on my system even your `print` approach works fine. But using the message stream is of course better style.

Comment: @Roland **Note that I have set workers to 2 so it can be run in parallel in most computers**. As far as I understand it, since there are 2 workers, it should output the first 2 messages at approximately 5 seconds, after 10 seconds 2 more and so on. All this assuming 2 cores/threads at least are available.

Comment: Ah, okay. No, the conditions are signaled after the worker has finished. You could change the chunk sizes and, e.g., set `future.scheduling = Inf`.

Comment: @Roland That does not work either... Messages appear at the end of execution. Is not there an option that does not rely on changing chunk sizes and messing with futures?

Comment: Easiest option: `sink` to a text file.

Comment: Are you just trying to show the progression of your parallel cycle? If so, there are better ways. Have a look at the R package `progressr`

Comment: @Edo I am aware of `progressr`, but it doesn't work when launching the script and outputing to a text file. @Roland I will have a look at sink, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be closer and builds on @Roland. `future_lapply(1:6, function(idx) {   Sys.sleep(idx);    message(paste0( idx, " completed. ", Sys.time() )) }, future.conditions = "message", future.stdout = NA)
`. It just adds `future.stdout = NA`. Note, the help suggests that using that option is not recommended.